# Tomcat 8 multipart requests taking longer to execute

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, multipartform-data, tomcat8

I have a spring boot application(war) hosted on a tomcat 8. In our application we have few api's which are multipart requests, and one of the api is very frequently used to push files which are of size around 10 to 20kb.

As the requests keep growing, tomcat is taking too long to handle these multi-part requests. I say that it is with tomcat because, I have enabled debug logs in my app along with spring security and the requests takes around 200ms to handle the request along with security.

The requests that I'm taking about are coming from another system which will send only 2 requests at any instance and will only send next ones once it gets the response.

During peak load time, these requests are taking around 20-30secs to respond on the whole. out of which my app logs are only 200-300ms.

I have configured the tomcat with default settings and only modified the connector to use NIO1 and ssl.

Here is my connector config

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslProtocol="TLS" 
clientAuth="false" keystorePass="secret" keystoreType="PKCS12" 
keystoreFile="path_to_pfx" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https"
/>
```

Did anyone come across such issue? I have been looking at tomcat docs and on google but could not find any leads.

I tried increasing the buffer size of the pool, but that did not help too.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excerpt from Tomcat documentation:

> Each incoming request requires a thread for the duration of that
> request. If more simultaneous requests are received than can be
> handled by the currently available request processing threads,
> additional threads will be created up to the configured maximum (the
> value of the maxThreads attribute). If still more simultaneous
> requests are received, they are stacked up inside the server socket
> created by the Connector, up to the configured maximum (the value of
> the acceptCount attribute). Any further simultaneous requests will
> receive "connection refused" errors, until resources are available to
> process them.

Generally, it's a good practice to have a reverse proxy like Nginx as slow connections will slow down your application dramatically.
Even though I think this is not the case with your program.

I think it's a good idea to debug Tomcat, enable debug log level or even add tomcat source code to your path and put breakpoints in relevant places or use an instrumentation tool like NewRelic to see what's going on inside your deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your response @jahan. I have been monitoring my deployment with elastic APM but that did not help much in finding the root cause. The issue is also intermittent, let me try the options you suggested. Thank you.